# file couldn't be deleted in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

What's the reason why an os in a virtual box cannot delete a file that is being used in the physical os. For example, I copied a movie from the virtual box and I put it into the physical os. Then I convert the video in the physical os. 
Why is that, when I try to permanently delete the copy of that file in the virtual box, it says that the file is currently in used.
But the fact is, it is not that exact same file which is being used because I copied it earlier. Which makes it 2 identical files.
What is the reason behind why I can't delete the copy of the file in the virtual box?

Comment: What are your host and guest operating systems?

Comment: host:7 and the guest is:xp

Comment: Is it possible that an application (converter, for example) still retains a lock on the file in the guest? You could try to use Process Monitor ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx ) to see if a process still has that file open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attempt to reboot guest os. if file released, then its look like bug or file locked by some process in guest os. If not released, then look like file really dont copied to host os...